# Why my query is returning the sum for all rows instead of the only matching one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this query. It works but the **TotalCost** remains the same for different parameters. I want it to change its value accordingly. Currently, it takes the sum of all rows but it should only take the sum of the rows that are returned by the query.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ServicesDetailedReportPartyWise] 

        @FromDate date= '01/Jun/2010',
        @ToDate date= '01/Oct/2018',
        @PartyName varchar(20)='B'

AS
BEGIN
        Set @ToDate= ISNULL(@ToDate, getdate());

        Select inv.InvoiceNo, Convert(varchar(11),inv.EntryDateTime,106) as EntryDateTime, s.ServiceName, c.VehicleRegNo, inv.ServicePrice, c.CustomerName, inv.Party as PartyName,
        inv.fk_BookingID, t.TotalCost, SUM(t.TotalCost) over () as TotalRevenue, ISNULL(SUM(inv.OwnerCommission) over(),0) as TotalCommission, ISNULL(inv.OwnerCommission,0) as Commission
        from dbo.[Services] s
        inner join invoices inv
        on inv.fk_ServiceID= s.ServiceID
        inner join customers c
        on c.CustomerID= inv.fk_CustomerID
        Cross join (Select SUM(inc.ServicePrice) as TotalCost from dbo.Invoices inc) t
        where inv.Party= @PartyName AND (convert(date, inv.EntryDateTime) between @FromDate and @ToDate)
        order by inv.EntryDateTime desc


END
```

---

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: According to my understanding, I suggested that use [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cross join` doing nothing with filtration, if you are going with that then you would need to do some filtration similar as `outer query`.

Other option would be to apply *window* function :

```
select inv.InvoiceNo, Convert(varchar(11),inv.EntryDateTime,106) as EntryDateTime, 
       s.ServiceName, c.VehicleRegNo, inv.ServicePrice, c.CustomerName, inv.Party as PartyName,
       inv.fk_BookingID, 
       sum(inv.TotalCost) over (partition by . . .) as TotalCost, 
       sum(inv.TotalCost) over () as TotalRevenue, 
       isnull(sum(inv.OwnerCommission) over(), 0) as TotalCom
       mission, isnull(inv.OwnerCommission,0) as Commission
 . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

`TotalCost` is `t.TotalCost`, where `t` is defined by:

```
(Select SUM(inc.ServicePrice) as TotalCost from dbo.Invoices inc) t
```

This sub-query **is not filtered at all**, and is simply the sum over the entire `dbo.Invoices` table - it is a single cell that you have then cross-joined to all the rows.

So: that's why it isn't changing.

If you want the sum over `inv`, you'll need to do grouping and summing over the groups.